# Overriding methods from different classes in java

Tags: java, class, overriding

From a [java tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm)

> - A subclass within the same package as the instance's superclass can override any superclass method that is not declared private or final.
> - A subclass in a different package can only override the non-final methods declared public or protected.

What is the difference though?If a method is not declared private then it must be public or protected no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, no.

A method can be public, protected, private or **package private**.
The method is package private if you don't specify an access modifier.

It's obvious why a class from a different package cannot overwrite package private members.

Answer (score 3):

This points can be rephrased as: *you can override only method to which your class have access to, and if this method is not final*.

So if you are creating class outside of package in which base class (or interface) is placed you can override only non-final *public* and *protected*  methods.

If derived class is in same package as base class then you can also override non-final methods without access modifier (package-protected).

You can never override private methods.